# getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: when running feature file in eclipse

Tags: selenium, cucumber

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/tagexpressions/TagExpressionParser
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberPropertiesParser.parse(CucumberPropertiesParser.java:81)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberPropertiesParser.parse(CucumberPropertiesParser.java:40)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:57)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:30)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.tagexpressions.TagExpressionParser
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the tag-expressions library as a dependency in Maven?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>tag-expressions</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```